# Solution to avoid the error: "Entry point not found " even though I'm checking the OS version before callingGetTcpTable2 api on windows XPindows XP?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, dll

I'm aware that the GetTcpTable2 api is supported only on windows vista and above versions, hence the code checks for the OS version and only then enters the loop that calls the api. I'm compiling the code on windows 7, visual studio 2008 and the executable runs fine on windows 7 and other OS except Windows XP, the error thrown is : [image: This is the error]

The code snippet is:`

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Need to link with Iphlpapi.lib and Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment(lib, "iphlpapi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#define MALLOC(x) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (x))
#define FREE(x) HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (x))
/* Note: could also use malloc() and free() */

int main()
{
    OSVERSIONINFOEX osvi;
    ZeroMemory(&osvi, sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX));
    osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX);
    GetVersionEx((OSVERSIONINFO *)&osvi);
    if(osvi.dwMajorVersion>=6)
    {
     // Declare and initialize variables
     PMIB_TCPTABLE2 pTcpTable;
     ULONG ulSize = 0;
     DWORD dwRetVal = 0;
     char szLocalAddr[128];
     char szRemoteAddr[128];
     struct in_addr IpAddr;
     int i;
     pTcpTable = (MIB_TCPTABLE2 *) MALLOC(sizeof (MIB_TCPTABLE2));
     if (pTcpTable == NULL)
     {
        printf("Error allocating memory\n");
        return 1;
     }

     ulSize = sizeof (MIB_TCPTABLE);
     // Make an initial call to GetTcpTable2 to
    // get the necessary size into the ulSize variable
     if ((dwRetVal = GetTcpTable2(pTcpTable, &ulSize, TRUE)) ==
        ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
        {
            FREE(pTcpTable);
            pTcpTable = (MIB_TCPTABLE2 *) MALLOC(ulSize);
            if (pTcpTable == NULL) 
            {
                printf("Error allocating memory\n");
                return 1;
            }
       }
     }
     else
      {
       printf("Unsupported OS");
      }
    return 0;    
}
```

`How do I get the executable to work on Windows XP without crashing/throwing the error shown in attached image?

Comment: Use `GetProcAddress` or [delay loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx).

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. I tried the delay loading part and that's exactly what I wanted, I wasn't sure of the terminology and you gave the exact solution! Thanks again @JonathanPotter

Comment: Wrong solution. Don't check for circumstantial information (OS version), but availability instead. Features have been backported in the past, and your solution precludes use of those features on those platforms. The comment by @JonathanPotter explains how to check for availability, as well as provides information for a clean implementation.

Comment: @IInspectable, thank you for the comment, I'll follow what you said, but with regard to the API I have used in this solution: ** GetTcpTable2 **, the msdn documentation has clearly mentioned the OS it supports! hence I'm checking for circumstantial information.

Comment: Writing more code to get a less functionality? I'm not convinced. Keep in mind that supported OS versions can change over time. Not just in theory. [This API call](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh310513.aspx), for example, was backported.